# css - center alignment not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heaversm/7ZSmX/) to have a horizontally and vertically centered `div` that stays 100% of the browser width and height, in which the text should be aligned center vertically and horizontally, but currently the top line of the text is aligning to the center, rather than having an overall center point being in the center of the 3 lines of text.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Regret</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Bowlby+One+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='css/regret.css' rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="inner">
                <h1>Regret</h1>
                <p class="choice">Let it out</p>
                <p class="choice">Wallow in it</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
body { font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive; margin:0; text-align:center; color: #5e7c88; }
h1, h2, h3 { font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive; color: #4b5f6d; }
img { border: 0; }

#container { margin: 0 auto; }
.choice { font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive; }
.inner {  position: absolute; top: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle should work (if I understood what you want correctly): http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSmX/23/. I basically use the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` properties.

Comment: yes, but I don't want to have to specify a height for the table (unless that height is 100% of the browser)

Comment: @mheavers. I just changed it (see fiddle in answer). Check it out now. It's 100% of the browser.

Comment: Nice one! Crazy how much work you have to go to just to center align something

Answer (score 0):

change inner to this

```
position:fixed; top: 50%; text-align:center; width:100%;
```

Comment: see comments to @John Riselvato

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix:
http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSmX/13/

```
.inner {  margin-top: 50%; }
```

is what you want to instead of relative.

Comment: doesn't seem to work once I give text a font-size: http://jsfiddle.net/heaversm/7ZSmX/15/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSmX/19/ there is your font issue. keep everything in .inner

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSmX/24/ it works perfect.

Comment: The example above is making the container much larger than it needs to be. The previous example was aligning the top of the text to the center of the browser rather than the center of the text.